# Better code for error handling in NodeJs and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express.js

I have this code for a post request, when the user wants to change his password. Because of all the cases and the following page renders the code came out really ugly. Is there a better way to structure this? (It works fine and does what I want.)

```
// Check if old password is correct
    SQL.getUserFromDB(request.session.username).then(function (results) {
        // Hash and compare with stored hash
        bcrypt.compare(request.body.oldPw, results[0].password, function (error, result) {
            // Log possible error
            if (error) console.log(error);
            if (result === true) {
                // Check if new passwords are both the same
                if (request.body.newPw === request.body.newPw2) {
                    // Call mysql function
                    SQL.changeUserPassword(request.session.username, request.body.newPw).then(function () {
                        response.render('pages/changePassword', {
                            user: request.session.username,
                            text: 'Passwort erfolgreich geändert.'
                        });
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        if (error == 'pw') {
                            response.render('pages/changePassword', {
                                user: request.session.username,
                                text: 'Neues Passwort zu unsicher.'
                            });
                        } else {
                            // Render error page
                            response.render('pages/changePassword', {
                                user: request.session.username,
                                text: 'Fehler beim Ändern des Passworts.'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Render error page
                    response.render('pages/changePassword', {
                        user: request.session.username,
                        text: 'Neue Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!'
                    });
                }
            } else {
                // Render error page
                response.render('pages/changePassword', {
                    user: request.session.username,
                    text: 'Altes Passwort stimmt nicht überein!'
                });
            }
        });
        // Catch sql errorsFehler beim Ändern des Passworts
    }).catch(function (error) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        response.render('pages/errors/loginFailed');
    });
```

I tried just setting the text in the different cases and rendering one page with the text at the bottom, this didn't work however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you first need to do is convert all non-promise/callback-based operations into promises, or wrap them in one. This way, you can write seamless promise-based code. For instance, convert `bcrypt.compare()` into:

```
const bcryptCompare = (pw1, pw2) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.compare(pw1, pw2, (error, result) => {
      if(error) reject(error)
      else resolve(result)
    })
  })
}
```

There are libraries that do this for you, and newer versions of libraries usually support promise-based versions of their APIs. But if you ever need to craft this yourself, this is how it's generally done.

Next, I would separate express from this logic. This way, you're not constrained with Express. Instead of accessing `request`, pass only the needed information to your function. Instead of immediately sending a response, consider throwing error objects instead. This way, you can defer your response logic to your routing logic.

Next, you could turn to `async`/`await` for cleaner code. It's just syntax sugar on top of Promises, allowing asynchronous code to look synchronous.

```
// Custom error class to house additional info. Also used for determining the
// correct response later.
class PasswordMismatch extends Error {
  constructor(message, user){
    this.message = 'Neue Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!'
    this.user = user
  }
}

class UserDoesNotExist extends Error {...}
class PasswordIncorrect extends Error {...}

// More custom error classes here

// Our logic, which knows nothing about express and only requires a few
// pieces of information for our operation.
const changePassword = async (username, oldPw, newPw, newPw2) => {

  // Throwing an error inside an async function rejects the promise it returns
  if (newPw !== newPw2) {
    throw new PasswordMismatch('Neue Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!', user)
  }

  const results = await SQL.getUserFromDB(username)

  if (!results) {
    throw new UserDoesNotExist('...', user)
  }

  const result = bcryptCompare(oldPw, results[0].password)

  if(result !== true) {
    throw new PasswordIncorrect('...', user)
  }

  try {
    SQL.changeUserPassword(username, newPw)
  } catch(e) {
    throw new PasswordChangeFailed('...', user)
  }
}

// In your express router
app.post('route', async (request, response) => {
  // Gather the necessary data from the request
  const username = request.session.username
  const oldPw = request.body.oldPw
  const newPw = request.body.newPw
  const newPw2 = request.body.newPw2

  try {
    await changePassword(username, oldPw, newPw, newPw2)

    // If the operation didn't throw, then we're good. Happy path.
    response.render('pages/changePassword', {
      user: username,
      text: 'Passwort erfolgreich geändert.'
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // If any of the operations failed, then we determine the right response

    // In this case, we used a custom error. We can get the data from it.
    // You can have more of these for the other custom classes.
    if(error instanceof PasswordConfirmError){
      response.render('pages/changePassword', {
        user: error.user,
        text: error.message
      });

    } else {
      // Generic 500 error, if all else fails.
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. That looks way nicer than what i hacked together.

Comment: Would you normally seperate the logic in different files?

Comment: @user3742929 Depends on  your case. Small script, you don't worry about it. But when the code grows, separate them. Also, one thing to consider is that `changePassword` in my example could be used regardless of the presence of express.